# JSoup cookie handling with redirect on GET

Tags: java, http, url, cookies, jsoup

I'm writing little application that have to handle login to page. I need to use login and password in URL to connect to application. For example: "www.page.com/dsd?login=xxx&password=yyy"

**I can use only jsoup.**

```
public Document getContentOfPage(String url) throws IOException {
    return Jsoup.connect(url)
            .userAgent("Mozilla")
            .cookies(getCookiesForSession(url))
            .timeout(50000)
            .get();
}

public Map<String, String> getCookiesForSession(String url) throws IOException {
    Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect(url)
            .method(Connection.Method.GET).timeout(50000).execute();
    return res.cookies();
}
```

Main problem is that I need to use GET two times. In cookies there are stored values of "session_id" and "login" that are generated while log into page. Jsoup just forgets cookies from page request and redirect me to login page. Is there any chance to maintain cookies in single GET method?

hint: *HttpGet works here perfectly.*

Comment: How about invoking `getCookiesForSession` only once, storing cookies somewhere and passing them as argument of `getContentOfPage` to avoid invoking `getCookiesForSession` again?

Comment: I need to check if I can log on to page. If I will store session id somewhere I will be able to log each time... Or if session id will be deleted from server I could not log at all. Good idea, but still not a good solution for me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the cookies.  Each request you make very well might change the cookies that you need to use. So I would keep them the entire tiem and adn update them each time you request another page.  They could be stored in the class if you reuse it, otherwise you will need to store them elsewhere and pass them.

So here your first step will be to have a login() function that will do the login and set these variables.

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect(url).method(Connection.Method.GET)
    .timeout(50000).execute();
this.sessionIdCookie = res.cookie("session_id");
this.loginCookie = res.cookie("login");
```

Then when you send in your getContentOfPage function you can use this from the class.

Comment: I will just need to use those cookies in next request. I want to use one get to log into page. So this solution is similar to that I've used. Best idea would be to use: "Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla").get();" but cookies disappear. I've tryed: "Jsoup.connect(url).cookies(new Map<String, String>()).userAgent("Mozilla").get();" but still it haven't worked